How to Combine Joint PMFs Using an Indicator Variable
I am trying to combine joint PMFs using an indicator variable and am having trouble understanding how to arrive at the final combined form. Here's the problem I'm working on:
Problem Statement:
One of two doctors, Dr. Hibbert and Dr. Nick, is called upon to perform a series of  n surgeries. Let  be the indicator random variable for Dr. Hibbert performing the surgeries, and suppose that E(H)=p. Given that Dr. Hibbert is performing the surgeries, each surgery is successful with probability a, independently. Given that Dr. Nick is performing the surgeries, each surgery is successful with probability b, independently. Let X be the number of successful surgeries.
(a) Find the joint PMF of H and X.
My Work So Far:
Define Variables:

H is the indicator random variable for Dr. Hibbert performing the
surgeries

P(H=1)=p

P(H=0)=1−p



X is the number of successful surgeries

Given  = 1,  follows a Binomial distribution with
parameters  and a: X∼Binomial(n,a)
Given  = 0,  follows a Binomial distribution with
parameters  and b: X∼Binomial(n,b)



Conditional PMF of X:

For H=1:

$$ P(X = k \mid H = 1) = \binom{n}{k} a^k (1 - a)^{n-k} $$

For H=0

$$ P(X = k \mid H = 0) = \binom{n}{k} b^k (1 - b)^{n-k} $$
Joint PMF of H and X:

For H= 1

$$ P(X = k, H = 1) = \binom{n}{k} a^k (1 - a)^{n-k} \cdot p $$

Similarly For H =0

$$ P(X = k, H = 0) = \binom{n}{k} b^k (1 - b)^{n-k} \cdot (1 - p)
 $$
My Issue:
I am trying to combine these individual joint PMFs into a single expression using the indicator variable H. I understand that H can take values 0 or 1, and the final form should look like this:
$$ P(X = x, H = h) = \binom{n}{x} \left( a^x (1 - a)^{n-x} \cdot p \right)^h \left( b^x (1 - b)^{n-x} \cdot (1 - p) \right)^{1-h}
$$
However, I am stuck at how to properly combine these PMFs into this form. I have tried following steps to derive the combined form but I am not confident about the approach. Could someone please provide a detailed explanation on how to reach this combined form using the indicator variable H?
Thank you in advance for your help!

$P(X=x, H=h) = 1_{{H=1}}P(X=x, H=1)+ 1_{{H=0}} P(X=x, H=0)$?

If a function $f(k,h)$ satisfies $f(k,0)=a(k)$ for $k\in\{0, ..., n\}$ and $f(k,1)=b(k)$ for $k \in \{0, ..., n\}$, you can equally express this in the following three acceptable ways:

Just say $f(k,0)=a(k)$ for $k\in\{0, ..., n\}$ and $f(k,1)=b(k)$ for $k \in \{0, ..., n\}$.

Say that for all $k\in\{0, .., n\}$ and $h\in\{0,1\}$ we have
$$ f(k,h) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} a(k) & \mbox{ if $h=0$} \\ b(k) & \mbox{if $h=1$}\end{array}\right.$$

Say that for all $k\in\{0, .., n\}$ and $h\in\{0,1\}$ we have
$$ f(k,h) = a(k)^{1-h}b(k)^h $$


Most people (including me) prefer the first two ways of expressing this function $f(k,h)$. The third way is more concise but less easy to understand. You can check the third way is correct because when $h=0$ the $b(k)$ term is killed because $b(k)^0=1$ for all $k$, while when $h=1$ the $a(k)$ term is killed. This assumes $a(k)\neq 0$ and $b(k)\neq 0$ to avoid the undefined case $0^0$.
So, you successfully solved the problem in your "Joint PMF of H and X" section, but you need to clarify that you are considering $P[(X,H)=(k,h)]$ for all $k \in \{0, 1, .., n\}$ and $h\in\{0,1\}$.
Note that
$$ {n \choose k}^h {n \choose k}^{1-h} = {n \choose k}$$

@Michael-Thank you for the clarification!
